# DropDown Aligned

Tags: html, css

I have a menu with dropdown option, I'm trying to align the dropdown menu under the respective item selected from list. So far is aligned to the left, the dropdown ul list is inside the element that should display the dropdown list.

I'm not sure about what I'm doing wrong here, some suggestion?

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/qjqagthw/)

HTML

```
    <div id="menu">

        <div id="menu-wrapper">
            <img id="home-icon" src="images/home.svg" />

            <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
                <li><a href="">NEWS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">MARINA GUIDE</a></li>
                <li class="submenu"><a href="">PRACTICAL</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Glossary</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Tips</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="">OUT AT SEA</a></li>
                <li><a href="">GEAR</a></li>
                <li><a href="">FORUM</a></li>
            </ul>
            </nav>

            <div id="menu-icon-container">
                <img id="menu-icon" src="images/menu.svg" />
            </div>

            <div id="menu-icon-container">
                <img id="menu-icon" src="images/search.svg" />
            </div>



        </div>
```

CSS

```
#menu-icon-container {
position: relative;
float: right;
height: 100%;
width: 60px;
background-color: ;

}

#menu-icon-container:hover {
background-color: #bf1b33;
cursor: pointer;
}

#menu-icon {
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
cursor: pointer;
}


#menu ul {
list-style:none;
position:relative;
float:left;
margin:0;
padding:0;
margin-left:20px;
}

#menu ul li {
display: inline;

}

#menu ul li a {
color: #00599b;
padding: 0px 15px;
text-decoration: none;
border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

#menu ul li a:hover {
border-bottom: 2px solid #bf1b33;
}

#menu ul ul
{
display:none;
position:absolute;
top:100%;

background: fuchsia;
padding:0
}

#menu ul ul li
{
float:none;
width:200px
}

#menu ul ul a
{
line-height:120%;
padding:10px 15px
}

#menu ul li:hover > ul
{
display:block
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `#menu ul li {` and `left:0;` to `#menu ul ul` will make it proper below the selected.

```
#menu ul li {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
}

#menu ul ul
{
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:100%;
    left:0;
    background: fuchsia;
    padding:0
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qjqagthw/1/)**

Comment: wow thanks @ketan updated and working thanks!!

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qjqagthw/4/)

Comment: @Connum I clicked on the check icon and it's telling me "you can't accept an answer in two minutes" I'm giving system a moment to try again:)! I will of course!!

Comment: @ketan my friend a question, I created another submenu for other elements and in jsfiddle when you hover one, it's only showing submenu of that element, but in my computer, same code, is showing both submenus at the same time while hovering only in one of them:( I've used a javascript code to show the submenu, do you know what's happening or why is displaying differently on my computer program compared with jsfiddle? [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qjqagthw/7/)

Comment: @Eugenio You have used same `id="menu-icon-container"` for multiple elements. Id must be unique.